# Update phone1 and phone2 with Moodle's webservice

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I read Moodle's API but I can't update phone1 and phone2 with user'ID with webservice.
The WS core_user_update_users doesn't take phone1 and phone2's field. 
How can I update these fields with webservice?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you cannot. You can, however, update custom user profile fields, so you may want to create phone(s) field(s) with custom profile field mechanism, and update it with the core_user_update_users webservice function[image]